# What is the difference between x RadToDeg cos x div and COSC?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,pst-func}
\begin{document}
\pstVerb{
    /SINC { dup 0 eq { pop 1 } { dup SIN exch div } ifelse } bind def %% in pst-math.pro
    /COSC { dup 0 eq { pop 1 } { dup COS exch div } ifelse } bind def %% based on \SINC
}
\psset{xunit=.5,yunit=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-15,-2)(15,2)
\psplot[plotpoints=500]{-15}{15}{x RadToDeg cos x div}
\uput[0](1,1){$y=\dfrac{cos(x)}{x}$}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-15,-2)(15,2)
\psplot[plotpoints=500]{-15}{15}{x COSC}
\uput[0](1,1){$y=\dfrac{cos(x)}{x}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question:

What is the difference between *x RadToDeg cos x div* and *COSC* ; *Div* and *div*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of `COSC` states `dup COS exch div`. Looking at the PostScript Stack Commands Reference (http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/Flat/stack-ref.html) this means:

1. add a duplicate copy of the top object of the stack to the stack
2. `COS`
3. exchange the position of the top two elements on the stack
4. divide

In `pst-math` the `COS function is defined as cosine on radians. From the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-math/doc/pst-math-doc.pdf) on page 4:

> pst-math introduces natural trigonometric PostScript operators COS, SIN and TAN defined by
>
> cos: ℝ → [−1,1], x → cos(x)

So `x COSC` becomes:

`x dup COS exch div`

→ `x x COS exch div`

→ `x COS x div`

→ `x radian_cos x div`,

i.e., `x RadToDeg cos x div`.

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen, can you answer the second problem? It is Div and div .

Comment: @TrongVuong your code didn't contain `DIV` or `Div`, so I wasn't sure what you meant by that question. But you can see the answer given by Red-Cloud below.

Answer (score 5):

`3 4 div` is valid, but `3 0 div` throws an error. With
`3 0 DIV` it is valid but returns simply `3`. That is the difference between `div` and `DIV`

Answer (score 3):

In order to understand what `DIV` and `COSC` do behind the scene, it will be better if you can recreate them  only with `pst-plot` as follows.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb{
    /DIV {dup 0 eq {pop 1}{} ifelse div} bind def
    /COSC {dup RadtoDeg cos exch DIV} bind def      
}
\psset{xunit=.5,yunit=2}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-15,-5)(15,5)
\psplot[plotpoints=500]{-15}{15}{x COSC}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Notes:

- `DIV` is just an operator that takes two operands `x` and `y` and returns `x/y` if `y` is not `0`. Otherwise, it returns `x/1=x`.

  Let's trace it step by step for non zero `y`.

  ```
  x y DIV
  x y dup 0 eq {pop 1}{} ifelse div
  x y y 0 eq {pop 1}{} ifelse div
  ```

  As `y 0 eq` return false then the continuation jumps to `{}` which is empty.

  ```
  x y div
  ```

  Let's trace it step by step for `y=0`.

  ```
  x 0 DIV
  x 0 dup 0 eq {pop 1}{} ifelse div
  x 0 0 0 eq {pop 1}{} ifelse div
  ```

  As `0 0 eq` return true then the continuation jumps to `{pop 1}`.

  ```
  x 0 pop 1 div
  ```

  `pop` removes the  top operand which is `0`.

  ```
  x 1 div
  x
  ```
- `COSC` is also just an operator that takes one operand `x` (in radian) and return `cos(x)/x` for non zero `x` and returns `cos(x)` for `x=0`.

  ```
  x  COSC
  x  dup RadtoDeg cos exch DIV    
  x  x RadtoDeg cos exch DIV
  x  x_deg cos exch DIV
  x  cos(x_deg) exch DIV
  cos(x_deg) x DIV
  ```

  Final result is `cos(x_deg)/x` for non zero `x` but `cos(x_deg)` for `x=0`.

Comment: @TrongVuong: Because I am learning Unity too seriously.